# Retrieve the picture associated with a Facebook Graph API PlaceTag node without /picture edge?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working with the latest version of Facebook's Graph API (v2.3).

I'm using the [`tagged_places`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/tagged_places/) edge on my user object to show a list of places where I've been tagged. According to the docs, this will include location tags on photos, videos, posts, statuses and links on my profile.

For each tagged place, I receive a [`PlaceTag` node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/place-tag). According to the docs I can use the `picture` edge to retrieve the picture which was tagged in this location - presumably this only works when the post in question is a photo (rather than status or link, etc).

However it seems that the `picture` edge was [removed from v2.3](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/place-tag/picture/) of the Graph API. When I perform a request for the picture against a PlaceTag, I get the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) picture edge for this type is deprecated for versions v2.3 and higher", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 12
  }
}
```

The docs don't provide an alternative for this removed edge.

How can I retrieve the picture which was associated with a specific `PlaceTag`? Is this possible with Graph API v2.3?

Thanks

Comment: [v2.3 version of docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/place-tag) still lists the `picture` edge (maybe wrongfully so), but also says, _“A picture representing this visit (this is always a default image)”_ – so probably not that helpful anyway. But since the `place` field refers to a page, you should be able to get the picture for that page instead.

Comment: I was hoping to find the picture that the person was tagged in, rather than a picture from the place's page - i.e. a photo of the user at that place, rather than the public profile of the place.

Comment: The tagged_places edge does not provide that data. Photos the user has been tagged in will be included in `/userid/photos`, so you’d have to look through that.

Comment: It looks like the [Photo object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo) doesn't let you see the photo's geolocation.

EDIT: (pressed Enter too quickly).
So does that mean it's not possible to tie geolocation and photo data together? i.e. it's impossible to pair geolocation and photo data together, despite them being available in Facebook's UI?
I can just look at either: locations that the user has been tagged, or photos that they're in.. but not get the locations of the photos that they're tagged in?