# Facebook API get picture from post

Tags: python, facebook

I am trying to get pictures from photo type posts on Facebook. I am using Python. I tried to access post_id/picture, but I keep getting:
facebook.GraphAPIError: (#12) picture edge for this type is deprecated for versions v2.3 and higher

Is there any alternative to the picture edge in v2.8? The documentation still lists picture as an option.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871314/retrieve-the-picture-associated-with-a-facebook-graph-api-placetag-node-without), [one of its comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871314/retrieve-the-picture-associated-with-a-facebook-graph-api-placetag-node-without#comment47881078_29871314) may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. Now to get the picture of a post you can call
`{post-id}?fields=picture,full_picture`
where `picture` returns the url of a thumbnail of the image, while `full_picture` returns the url of the real image.